# get unshifted items from array and redisplay them angularjs

Tags: javascript, angularjs, protocols

Hi all I have a shopping cart list that displays 3 items at a time.
I can use the javascript protocol shift to move the items by one and display the next items on the list making it look like it's scrolling. I use push to pass the shifted items into a new array. It does show the items added but it doesn't shift to the previous items.
here is what I got so far [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/wayko/vp32u0yd/20/)
and here is a live view of the site [live site](http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/)

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("moxierevere",['ngCart']);
app.filter('myFilter', function () {
    return function (items, count) {
        var result = [];
        for (var i = 0; i < items.length && result.length < count; ++i) {
            if (items[i].available > 0) result.push(items[i]);
        }
        return result;
    };
});
app.controller("ItemsController",['ngCart', '$scope', function(ngCart, $scope){

ngCart.setTaxRate(0.00);
ngCart.setShipping(2.99); 
this.items = allItems;
$scope.itemsPerListing = 3;
var shifteditem = [];
var shifteditems = [];

 $scope.nextPage = function () {
  this.items = allItems;
    if($scope.itemsPerListing >= this.items.length)
    {
        $scope.itemsPerListing =  this.items.length;
    }
    else
    {
    shifteditem.push( $scope.items.shift());
    console.log(shifteditem);
    }   
  };

$scope.prevPage = function() {
this.items = allItems;
shifteditems.unshift(shifteditem);
console.log( shifteditems);

};
}]);
var allItems = [
{
id:0,
name: "item1",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/br.JPG" ,
price: 2.00,
available: 10,
size: "S , M, L"
},
{
id:1,
name: "item2",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/avacados.JPG" ,
price: 5.00,
available: 10,
size: "S , M, L"
},
{
id:2,
name: "item3",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/chicha.JPG" ,
price: 2.00,
available: 3,
size: "S , M, L"
},
{
id:3,
name: "item4",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/lomo.JPG" ,
price: 6.00,
available: 4,
size: "S , M, L"
},
{
id:4,
name: "item5",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/satuna.JPG" ,
price: 2.00,
available: 5,
size: "S , M, L"
},
{
id:5,
name: "item5",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/satuna.JPG" ,
price: 2.00,
available: 5,
size: "S , M, L"
},
{
id:6,
name: "item5",
image: "http://dreamcpu.com/moxierevere/images/satuna.JPG" ,
price: 2.00,
available: 5,
size: "S , M, L"
}
];  
})();
```

Comment: I thought of using .copy and reset my current view with the new data

Comment: Why do you bother shift etc? can you just put 3 items in a new array in scope?

Comment: if an item in the array doesn't contain data the filter doesn't add the items to the result array. the filter is outside the controller so can not access the result array

Comment: I still don't get your point. Why can't you use the same filter on the original array and get all 3 elements?

Answer (score 1):

You don't want to be shifting the items off of the array with the full set of data. Instead, get the scroll index and copy the 3 items into a new scope variable. Your scroll buttons should increment or decrement a $scope.index variable.

```
$scope.$watch('index', function(newVal, oldVal){
    $scope.displayedItems = [$scope.items[newVal], $scope.items[newVal + 1], $scope.items[newVal + 2] ];
});
```

That watches the index and updates the displayed items.

Comment: sorry I am new to angular and I am trying to wrap my mind on this

Comment: No its no problem, basically you want to leave the full data set intact and have a subset displayed. It happens in many different situations.

Comment: If you modify the original array, those items are deleted from the array, so you can't bring them back, unless you do something else, like this

Comment: in this example index would be used to change the this.items amount? would I have to change the filter ?

Comment: in this example the index is the starting point for whichever 3 items are going to be displayed. it should work well with the filter

Comment: so start with `$scope.index = 0` and item[0] item[1] and item[2] will be displayed. Click next page button, and item[1] , [2], and [3] will be displayed, (or 3, 4, 5 depending on what behavior you wanted out of it)

Comment: so currently my function shows 3 items using $scope.itemsPerListing  if I change it to 4, 4 items are shown. but how does adding the watch to change the displayed items work? I will still have to create the function to display the next item for it to work?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/83259/discussion-between-jose-ortiz-and-j-dizzle).

Answer (score 0):

Was finally able to get it to work using shift and unshift
still have to handle the counter to handle the index correctly but it works so far.

```
$scope.nextitem = function () {
  this.items = allItems;
    if($scope.itemsPerListing >= this.items.length)
    {
        $scope.itemsPerListing =  this.items.length;
        console.log($scope.itemsPerListing);
    }
    else
    {
    shifteditem.push( $scope.items.shift());
    counter = shifteditem.length;
     console.log(this.items.length);
     if (counter > $scope.itemsPerListing)
     {
         counter  = this.items.length + 2;

     }
    }        
  };

$scope.previtem = function() {
this.items = allItems;

if(counter > 0){
    $scope.items.unshift(shifteditem[counter-1]);
    counter = counter - 1;
    console.log(counter);
}   
};
}]);
```